# Why images can't upload them with a django2 form?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to make a form, with the ModelForm class, for people to be recruited by a small company. So I need photo of their identity card (face and back) and their life card. The problem is that when I send the form, after selecting the photos from my computer, it does not register in the database (not even the path), and they do not a copy to the desired media folder. By cons, if I do it from the admin, it works, I can even open the image in my browser. However, they still do not upload to the media folder.

models.py :

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserExtention (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='utilisateur')
    phone_number = models.CharField (max_length = 10, null = True, blank=True, verbose_name='numéro de téléphone')
    postal_code = models.IntegerField (null = True, blank=True, verbose_name='code postal')
    town = models.CharField (max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='ville')
    address = models.CharField (max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='adresse')
    id_card_recto = models.ImageField (upload_to = 'pictures/id_card_recto', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="photo du recto de la carte d'identité") 
    id_card_verso = models.ImageField (upload_to = 'pictures/id_card_verso', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="photo du verso de la carte d'identité")
    vital_card = models.ImageField (upload_to = 'pictures/vital_card', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="photo de la carte vitale")
    hours_number = models.IntegerField (null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="nombre d'heure effectuée par le salarié")


    def __str__(self):
        return "Profil de {}".format(self.user.username)
```

forms.py :

```py
from django import forms
from .models import UserExtention
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'password',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            )

class UserExtentionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserExtention
        exclude = ('user', 'hours_number')
```

views.py :

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserForm, UserExtentionForm

def registration (request):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES)
    form2 = UserExtentionForm(request.POST or None)
    envoi = False
    if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        user_extention = form2.save(commit = False)
        user_extention.user = user
        user_extention.save()
        envoi = True

    return render (request, 'registration/registration.html', locals())
```

The template :

```
<h1>Ceci est la page principale de l'application nommée "Registration"</h1>
{% if not envoi %}
<form action="{% url "registration" %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p}}
    {{ form2.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">    
</form>
{% else %}
<p>Votre inscription a bien été prise en compte, vous pouvez à présent vous connecter dans l'onglet <a href="#">connexion</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Thanks for answer !

Comment: You should pass the `request.FILES` to the `UserExtentionForm`, not the `UserForm`, since that form contains image form fields.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. It works! It's a beginner mistake! Thanks really.

Answer (score 0):

The form where you have media form fields is the `UserExtentionForm`, but in your code, you pass `request.FILES` only to the `UserForm`, that has no such media fields.

```
def registration (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form2 = UserExtentionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user_extention = form2.save(commit = False)
            user_extention.user = user
            user_extention.save()
            return redirect('some-view-name')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
        form2 = UserExtentionForm()
    return render (
        request,
        'registration/registration.html',
        {'form': form, 'form2': form2}
    )
```

Your view however contains some serious anti-patterns that are now (partially) migitated by the proposed solution:

1. you should *not* use `request.POST or None`, since a valid POST request can be empty, but it is still a POST request;
2. in case the POST request is successful, you should make a redirect, to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get); and
3. please do *not* use `locals()`, since it will pass all variables to the template, even uninteded ones. Furthermore since it is not clear *what* you pass to the template, later you might be tempted to remove some variables from your view for optimization, and the IDE will not raise a warning/error that these variables are still necessary in the template.

If you want to add a message that the submission was successful, I advise you to use [*Django's messaging framework* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/), and not pass a variable through the context. This framework is designed to post messages, regardless of the template itself, and prevent showing the same message multiple times.

Comment: OK thanks for answer me, I will do that 's you tell. (sorry for my English, I am French )